# ogmios standalone running in a different computer that is running cardano-node

Tags: cardano-node, node, mainnet

is it possible to run Ogmios standalone in a different computer that is running cardano-node. it happens that i already have cardano-node running in a computer but i dont want to overload that with Ogmios and want to run it in another equipment. Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible.

You need to connect to the Cardano node socket on the Node PC from your Ogmios PC over the network. To do this, you can use the `socat` command (assuming you're running on Linux.
See here for instructions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714010

Make sure your firewall is configured correctly.

Then you can simply follow the [Ogmios Standalone](https://ogmios.dev/getting-started/docker/#running-bare-hands) instructions to connect to the socket on the Ogmios PC.